# Javascript: How to preserve line feeds, tabs and spaces in xml text nodes

Tags: json, xml

An example will be simplest:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><topNode>Some text.
A new line.

A new line after a blank line.
    A new line after four spaces.
    A new line after a tab.
</topNode>
```

These texts are edited by users in textareas, so I have no idea what will be in them, but the users will want to preserve the formatting.

So then I need to save the file.

First I use `jQuery.parseXML()` to put this into an xml object.  Then I add lots of other xml nodes.  Then I use `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(critXML)` to get the whole thing back into text for saving.  All the formatting is lost.

Code beautifying after the fact won't know where the original formatting was.

Question 1: How do I preserve the formatting in the xml?

Question 2: Is json better at preserving formatting?  I would think it would be since json operations seem to preserve formatting generally.  But I don't want to go down that road unless I know it will work.

I could manually construct the xml as text, but that seems like a pain.

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: How do you know the formatting isn't being lost in the "then I add lots of other XML nodes" part, of which you've given us no details? [The formatting is preserved just fine across parsing and serialization.](https://jsfiddle.net/7dxgmww3/)

Comment: @JLRishe: XMLSerializer does remove formatting of the xml itself, so I figured that was what was removing my text node formatting.  Perhaps not...  I've started a json version which is going well, so this question may be moot.  I'll update if I find out what the problem was.  Thanks.

Comment: The link I provided demonstrates (at least in Chrome) that `XMLSerializer` preserves formatting in the text nodes.